# Add a string to new List<string>(new string[] { });

Tags: c#, string, list

How do you add a array of strings to a List?

```
 string csv = "one,two,three"; 
 string[] parts = csv.Split(',');

 _MyList.Add(new ListObjects()
 {
     Name = tag.Name,
     MyObjectList = new List<string>(new string[] { parts })
 });
```

This works:

```
 _MyList.Add(new ListObjects()
 {
     Name = tag.Name,
     MyObjectList = new List<string>(new string[] { "one", "two", "three" })
 });
```

But then this is hardcoded. Is it even possible to split a string by "," and then add those values to a List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ToList()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) method to convert the Array to a List.

```
string csv = "one,two,three";
string[] parts = csv.Split(',');

_MyList.Add(new ListObjects()
{
     Name = tag.Name,
     MyObjectList = parts.ToList()
});
```

Comment: Alle of the answers work, but I accept this as answer :D, upvoted all other answers, thank all of you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `parts` is an *array* already, just pass it to the `List`'s constructor:

```
 string csv = "one,two,three"; 
 string[] parts = csv.Split(',');

 _MyList.Add(new ListObjects()
 {
     Name = tag.Name,
     MyObjectList = new List<string>(parts)
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`ToList<TSource>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to do this:

```
var List = csv.Split(',').ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is simply to use `string.split`, followed by `.ToList()`, like so:

```
string csv = "one,two,three";

List<string> Strings = csv.Split(',').ToList();
```